# "CiviCRM Installed" screen lies

Tags: installation, drupal-7

[image: CiviCRM Installed (but not really)]
[image: Status report]
[image: People page]
[image: Modules page]

CiviCRM 5.40.1 isn't really installed it seems. Or at least not fully. Or maybe I'm an idiot.

I'm logged in as an Administrator. The 'review these permissions' link sends me to the Persons page which doesn't show the whole list of CiviCRM security check boxes, or at least the ones I'm used to seeing. If I click on the 'configure CiviCRM' link in the Status report, I just get the "CiviCRM Installed" page again.

Comment: What happens if you go to example.org/civicrm ? According to the code, this might happen if the civicrm.settings.php could not be read (same location as the Drupal settings.php).

Comment: Same thing, the "CiviCRM Installed" screen as shown above is displayed.

Comment: actually i don't find the file civicrm.settings.php anywhere, so hmmm

Comment: Are you using Drupal multisite? or files are in 'default'?

Comment: No and No. I did the standard installation for a new site (or at least I thought so.)